# Trigger in WPF is not working

Tags: wpf, triggers, controltemplate

I have a `ListView`, with `ListView.View` as `GridView`.

Default, the `mouseOver` is working, `ListViewItem` get highlighted when I mouseover, and get selected when I click it. But after I modified the `ControlTemplate`, I get the template I want, but the highlight and select is gone.

I use trigger, but it's not working.

Here is my code.

```
<Style x:Key="filesListViewItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding FileIsSelected}"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                        <Grid Height="40">
                            <GridViewRowPresenter/>
                            <Line X1="0.0" Y1="0.0" X2="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}}" Y2="0.0" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="2" Stroke="Gray" />
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

In my template, I actually added a line as a separator between 2 rows of `ListViewItem`.

I just don't get it why the trigger is not working!

Comment: Please check against the default ControlTemplate for ListViewItem to see if you haven't missed anything. Or you could take that up as a base and tweak it to your liking. I generally tend to avoid ControlTemplates replacement (unless absolutely required) because I'm not sure I understand all the intricacies..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Background property of a Control is only used in the ControlTemplate.  You have replaced the template with one that does not use Background, so setting the property has no effect.  You can use `{TemplateBinding Background}` to bind properties to the Background of the Control.  Perhaps you want to bind the Background of the Grid to it:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
    <Grid Height="40" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
        <GridViewRowPresenter/>
```